# Accessing JSON objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a json file that looks kind of like this:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Lookup": null,
      "Result": {
        "Paths": [
          {
            "Domain": "VALUE1.LTD",
            "Url": "",
            "Text1": "",
            "Modules": [
              {
                "Name": "VALUE",
                "Tag": "VALUE",
                "FirstDetected": "1111111111",
                "LastDetected": "11111111111"
              },
              {
                "Name": "VALUE",
                "Tag": "VALUE",
                "FirstDetected": "111111111111",
                "LastDetected": "11111111111111"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I print only the domain and access only the module.names in ruby and print the module.names to the console:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = File.read('input.json')
```

and does any one know of any good resources for ruby and json for someone new to it?

Comment: This `json =JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))` will create hash from json.

Comment: ah. I'm trying to create json files for each costumer file and then only access certain values (for example module.names). How is that done with json?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Comment: I have already created the json files.. Now I'm trying to access only the module.name from each json file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reduce your JSON to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate what you want to do. Anything beyond that clutters the question and makes it harder for us to help you. Your JSON sample is also invalid because of the curly-quotes and missing open `{`. JSON is well documented as it's a standard. Ruby tutorials abound all over the internet. Searching for either would turn up a lot of information. And asking for tutorials in either is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question will likely be closed because you are not demonstrating any attempt to solve the problem yourself, and are asking a question that is answerable through basic study of primary doc sources

Answer (score 8):

`JSON.parse` takes a JSON string and return a hash which can be manipulated just like any other [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

# Symbolize keys makes the hash easier to work with
data = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'), symbolize_keys: true)

# loop through :Results if there are any
data[:Results].each do |r|
  # loop through [:Result][:paths] if there are any
  r[:Result][:paths].each do |path|
    # path refers the current item
    path[:Modules].each do |module|
      # module refers to the current item
      puts module[:name]
    end if path[:Modules].any?
  end if r[:Result][:paths].any?
end if data[:Results].any?
```

Comment: On a side note: your JSON sample looks invalid - the quotes around the keys `Text1` and `Modules` are wrong.

Comment: what is the different between Modules and module? (assuming Modules is from my json file).

Comment: `:Modules` is a key in the `path` hash. `module` block variable containing the current item when iterating over `path[:Modules].each`

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby you have to use square brackets to access hashes.

```
json =JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))
domains = []
json.Results.map{|result| result.Paths.map{|path| domains << path.Domain }}
```

However it is Ruby... so you also can override the Hash class and access your Hashes with a simple dot notation. (by the simple solution of: @papirtiger )
For example: domain = json.Results.Paths.Domain

```
require 'ostruct'
JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'), object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Comment: Which seems like a really messy way to do this: `JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'),  object_class:  OpenStruct)`

Comment: Liked yours better and edited mine... thx for sharing!

Comment: Also json["Results"] and "Paths" are arrays. So you cannot access them as in your example - you need to iterate over them.

Comment: works but only in ruby 2.x, see https://coderwall.com/p/74rajw/convert-a-complex-nested-hash-to-an-object for an other sample

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
json_file = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))

json_file[:Results].each {|y| y[:Result][:Paths].each do |a|
  puts "Domain names: #{a[:Domain]}"
  a[:Modules].each {|b| puts "Module names are: #{b[:Name]}" }
end
}

#=> Domain names: VALUE1.LTD
#=> Module names are: VALUE
#=> Module names are: VALUE
```

Comment: Won't work, you need to parse the JSON file, not just read its contents.

Comment: @papirtiger forgot about that, thanks for pointing it out.